# java.lang.ClassCastException while extracting error message from SOAPFault

Tags: java, web-services, soap

I am trying to extract the error code and error message for the soapFault resposne of a webservice but getting ClasscasrException :

Below is the webservice response:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soapenv:Header xmlns:com="http://com.amdocs.bss.bsl/" xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
      <bsl:BSLResponseHeader xmlns:bsl="http://com.amdocs.bss.bsl/">
         <ResponseTimestamp>2015-02-24T11:34:03.419+01:00</ResponseTimestamp>
         <MessageID>1234</MessageID>
         <BSLServiceOperation>getTariffAndAddOns getTariffAndAddOns</BSLServiceOperation>
      </bsl:BSLResponseHeader>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <soapenv:Fault>
         <faultcode>soapenv:Server</faultcode>
         <faultstring>BSL exception</faultstring>
         <detail xmlns:com="http://com.amdocs.bss.bsl/" xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
            <bsl:error xmlns:bsl="http://com.amdocs.bss.bsl/">
             <errorCode>BSL-14004</errorCode>
          <errorMessage>OMS login failure: Problem in OMS UAMS login - 
Nested Exception/Error:
java.net.ConnectException: Tried all: '1' addresses, but could not connect over HTTP to server: '195.233.102.177', port: '40123'
</errorMessage>
          <detail>
            <ImplRetrieveCustomerAssignedProductRestOutput>
              <transactionId>1424678882788</transactionId>
              <?xml-multiple errorInfo?>
              <errorInfo>
                <errorCode>14004</errorCode>
                <errorMessage>OMS login failure: Problem in OMS UAMS login - 
Nested Exception/Error:
java.net.ConnectException: Tried all: '1' addresses, but could not connect over HTTP to server: '195.233.102.177', port: '40123'
</errorMessage>
                <sourceSystem>MCSS</sourceSystem>
              </errorInfo>
            </ImplRetrieveCustomerAssignedProductRestOutput>
            <httpstatusCode>500</httpstatusCode>
          </detail>
            </bsl:error>
         </detail>
      </soapenv:Fault>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Blow is the code to handle :

```
catch (SOAPFaultException e) {


      SOAPFault fault=e.getFault();
      Detail soapfaultdeDetail= fault.getDetail();
      Iterator detailEntries = soapfaultdeDetail.getDetailEntries();
      System.out.println("kk");
      while(detailEntries.hasNext()){
          DetailEntry newEntry = (DetailEntry)detailEntries.next(); 
          if( newEntry!=null ){
              final Iterator childElementsIter =               newEntry.getChildElements();
              while ( childElementsIter.hasNext() ) {


                  final SOAPElement soapElement = (SOAPElement) childElementsIter.next();  
                  if(soapElement.getElementName().getQualifiedName()!=null &&  soapElement.getElementName().getQualifiedName().equalsIgnoreCase("errorMessage") ){
                      String name=soapElement.getElementName().getQualifiedName();
                      String value = soapElement.getValue();
                      System.out.println(name +" : "+value);
                  } else if(soapElement.getElementName().getQualifiedName()!=null && soapElement.getElementName().getQualifiedName().equalsIgnoreCase("errorcode")){
                      String name=soapElement.getElementName().getQualifiedName();
                      String value = soapElement.getValue();
                      System.out.println(name +" : "+value);
                      } 

              }
          }

      }
}
```

Below is the output :

errorCode : BSL-14004
errorMessage : OMS login failure: Problem in OMS UAMS login - 
Nested Exception/Error:
java.net.ConnectException: Tried all: '1' addresses, but could not connect over HTTP to server: '195.233.102.177', port: '40123'

Exception in thread "Main Thread" java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.impl.TextImpl
    at msisdn.getTariffsAndAddOns(msisdn.java:155)
    at msisdn.main(msisdn.java:181)

`final SOAPElement soapElement = (SOAPElement) childElementsIter.next();`  (This is the 155th line

From the error position it looks like, first two conditions were executed successfully but while doing it third time it throws exception. Can someone please suggestion what should i do to avoid this?

Comment: Which line is line 155?

Comment: final SOAPElement soapElement = (SOAPElement) childElementsIter.next();   is the 155th line

Comment: Well then your problem is that you're trying to cast a TextImpl to SOAPElement, and TextImpl doesn't extend or implement SOAPElement.

Comment: Then it should give error in first two output also, but it gives error while running the loop on third time. and when i tried to insert another blank else in the loop after else if. It is working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure that first two times you are getting TextImpl. Clearly, it is failing because it is trying to type cast TextImpl to SoapElement. If you are expecting only SoapElement types, then maybe you can check

```
if (childElementIter.next() instanceof SoapElement) 
{ 
    // business logic 
}
```

Comment: Yeah, i tried that also it still gives the issue but with this condition, it runs only one time to print error message but not error code. Below is the output this time.

kk
errorMessage : Customer ID is not found
Exception in thread "Main Thread" java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.impl.TextImpl
 at msisdn.getTariffsAndAddOns(msisdn.java:155)
 at msisdn.main(msisdn.java:182)